# Load balancing a simple website (Apache)

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, load-balancing

I have two webservers colocated in the same place.  Currently only 1 is active and it hosts a online forum, but it's biggest use by far is serving large binary files to a couple hundred thousand people and responding to automated update checks.  Users reported that there have been some issues so I got the second webserver to share some of the load (I'm rsyncing between the two).  How can I implement an effective (simple) load balancer for these two servers?  The facility doesn't offer any sort of load balancing for me.

Round robin seems ineffective and not really a proper choice.

Comment: what are the problems being reported?  what is the current bottleneck?

Comment: Users reported that when they click a link (php link) which sends them a PHP header Location(thefile), that they get a strange message "Copyright 2002-2011 Google Inc.". And that's the only thing which loads on the page.  I figure it must be that the server is overloaded, so I just assumed a second server would solve the problem.   EDIT: The link is sent via an email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HA-Proxy is your friend. You can find it at http://haproxy.1wt.eu/

It's not the simplest thing to set up, but the price is nice. As far as I am aware, it is the de-facto load balancing standard in the open source world.

Comment: Actually a really basic setup is pretty straight forward for anyone who knows how to navigate `vi`